# Link is moving slightly on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, nav

When I hover over the link, the links are moving slightly. How can I solve this problem. Can't we solve it without using box-sizing property?

Here is my markup.

```
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
     <nav  class="paging">
        <ul>
             <li class="first"><a href="#">first</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
             <li><strong>3</strong></li>
             <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
             <li><span>...</span></li>
             <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
             <li class="last"><a href="#">last</a></li>
         </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is the styling for the markup.

```
 body{
     margin:0;
     color:#333;
     font:14px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     background:#fff;
 }

 a{color:#3c8fdc;}
 #wrapper{
     width:600px;
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:45px 0 0;
 }
.paging ul{
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     list-style:none;
     overflow:hidden;
 }
.paging li{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 4px 0 0;
}
.paging .first a, 
.paging .last a{
   text-align:left;
   width:auto;
   margin:0 9px;
}
.paging a{
   width:24px;
   padding:4px 0;
   display:block;
}
.paging .first a:before, 
.paging .last a:after{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.paging .first a:before{
  content:'<<';
  margin:0 4px 0 0;
}
.paging .last a:after{
  content:'>>';
  margin:0 0 0 4px;
}
.paging strong,
.paging a:hover{
  background:#f8f8f8;
  border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
.paging strong{
   display:block;
   padding:4px 0;
   width:22px;
}
.paging a:hover{
   color:#000;
   text-decoration:none; 
}
.paging span{
   display:block;
   padding:4px 3px 0;
}
```

For further clarity I have placed a short GIF image which link can be found here.http://screen.w3.ua/Aug14/30191123.gif

Answer (score 2):

At a very quick glance, it looks like you add a border.  Change border to outline for a:hover.  This can give compatibility issues with older IE, however.

Edit:

To overcome the hidden borders, replace

```
.paging ul{ overflow:hidden; }
```

with

```
.paging ul{ overflow:visible; }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jckxekqc/1)

Comment: Providing outline is not an ideal task. It just takes out the upper border.

Comment: Ah, I see you are hiding anything outside your "framing" nav element.  Simply show it to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `box-sizing:border-box;` to ur `.paging a`

hope it will help **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/mcurq9sz/)**

Comment: It worked for other links but the link at .paging .first and .paging .last is still moving.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

**Box Model without hover have no border**

[image]

**Box Model with hover have border of 1 px**

[image]

---

But I suggest **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m3ny79wa/)** (i.e. adding a transparent border to the anchor tags)

css

```
.paging a {
    width:24px;
    padding:4px 0;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid transparent; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: I actually thought about this (but was thinking of applying "none" to "border-style"(not sure if that would work).  I'd actually use this way as the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a border on hover, which pushes the box model out.

```
border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
```

If you don't want the border on regular state, simply make it the same as the background color, or provide padding to match the hover overall dimension.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding a 1px border to your links on hover. The easiest way to solve your problem is by replacing this css code:

```
.paging a{
   width:24px;
   padding:4px 0;
   display:block;
}
```

with the following:

```
.paging a{
   width:24px;
   padding:4px 0;
   display:block;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

What we have done here, is adding a transparent 1px border. This takes care of the adding a border on hover, it now just replaces the color of the border.